# Is it possible to emulate ARUBA device in GNS3 environment?

Tags: switch, gns3, aruba

Is it possible to emulate ARUBA device in GNS3 environment?

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for resources.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. GNS3 is limited to Cisco devices due to being based on Dynamips.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My question had second part. But it was edited. If GNS3 doesn't support Aruba devices, then are there other options for emulating ArubaOS?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here as on most SE sites. I don't know of any simulations either.